# How can I retrieve a mongodb collection using spring-data?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I want to retrieve  `List<Document>` (as an example) of all documents in a MongoDB collection for given `mongo` shell query.

Comment: I do not think it should be `MongoRepository<Document,String>` instead it should be `MongoRepository<YourModel,String>`, unless Document is not of type `org.bson.Document` of which I think it is...Take a look at this [tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/18156/spring-boot-mongodb) on how to  use  `MongoRepository`

Comment: yes , but are there any possibility to retrieve a mongo collection in List<Document> ?

Comment: You have this all wrong. You need a model with the same structure as your Document, Mongo will map the Document to your model. Follow the tutorial, also read about how document based databases work.

Comment: You can use the `MongoTemplate#find` _or_ `MongoRepository#findAll` methods to retrieve all documents in a database collection as a `java.util.List<T>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve a collection without mapping `Document` to a domain model.
Not sure whats the purpose you are chasing, but here you have an example:

```
package com.answers.stackoverflow.spring.mondbretrievedata.data;

import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class MongoRepository {
    private static final String DatabaseName = "EXAMPLE";
    private static final String CollectionName = "example";

    @Autowired
    private MongoClient client;

    public List<String> allDocuments() {
        final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        final MongoCollection<Document> data = client.getDatabase(DatabaseName).getCollection(CollectionName);
        data.find().map(Document::toJson).forEach(list::add);
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not return a json but a string with escaped double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `MongoRepository`, you have to give a `PersistentEntity`. So use your model class which is to be extended by `MongoRepository`

```
public interface YOUR_MODEL_Repository extends MongoRepository<MODEL_CLASS, String> {

}
```

Comment: yes i know , so how can i do in order to retrieve a collection in a List<Document> ?

Comment: Why don't you use `findAll()` method to reterive all documents in a collection?

Comment: Let me know the purpose to convert `List<Your_Model>` to `List<Document>`?

Comment: why i dont use findAll() ? because in my case , i only want to iterate through a collection , i don't want to persist any data , so i think it is useless to create a model class just for reading a document. In fact , the data retrieved from that document will be used with other data to create another model

Comment: `MongoRepository` will by default provide you with the generic methods of persistence entity. So I don't think that you can extend it with `Document`. But in your case you can use 1.create Generic repository or use 2. `MongoTemplate`. Java always gives importnce to type safety, that's why it expect mostly persistence entity. I feel it will be a wrong choice if you use Generic repositories which causes few problems for further development.

Comment: If you answer helps you please tick and upvote to help people who seek this kind of question

Answer (score -1):

See example official on [Product -> getAttributes()](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-book/blob/master/mongodb/src/main/java/com/oreilly/springdata/mongodb/core/Product.java) for more details visit [Spring Data - Mongo DB](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-book/tree/master/mongodb)